# Can we send custom push notifications to independent users using Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am planning to implement notifications in my Angular 4 web app using Google Firebase. Every user in my application will have his own set of notifications. I have seen that Firebase can broadcast the messages to a user group or to the subscribers of a topic. But, is there any way to send customized notifications to independent users? If I have to use Pub-Sub pattern, is it a right approach to create a topic for every user id and push notifications to those topics?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sending messages programmatically from a backend or using the Notifications composer in the Firebase console?

Comment: I am planning to log events in the database and based on the event, the user affected by that event should be notified with some custom message programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

When you use Firebase Cloud Messaging in an app (Web, Android, or iOS) it gets a unique Instance ID (also often called a Device Registration Token). This Instance ID can be used to unique identify that specific app on that specific device.

If you want to send a message to that specific app on that specific device, you can send a message to the Instance ID as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message#http_request).

If a user uses the same app on multiple devices, and you want to send a message to the user on all devices, you'll typically combine the Instance IDs into a so-called device group as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group).

Finally, if you want to send a message to a group of users who have all subscribed to a specific topic, you can send the message to that pub/sub topic as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging).

Given your description it sounds like you're looking to either send to the Instance ID or to a device group.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My web application is a portal where every user has his own account. For example, when I logged into my Stack Overflow account I have seen a notification when you have responded to my question. This notification is specific to me. I am trying to achieve something like this using Firebase. I am planning to log events in the database and based on the event, the user affected by that event should be notified with some custom message.

Comment: All sounds feasible. I wrote a blog post a while ago that used topics to accomplish user-targeted messages: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, it makes sense. I have learned that these notifications are not fit for IOS - as they don't support service workers. Do we have any alternative for IOS devices? FYI - I am not building a native application, it is just a responsive web app.

Comment: I'm not aware of any push notification technology for web apps on iOS.